# How to restore mysql database in XAMPP?

Tags: mysql, xampp, backup, innodb

I have a backup of the entire `xampp/mysql` folder. How can I use it to recover my old db on a fresh installation of XAMPP?

Simply copying the old `xampp/mysql` folder to new xampp leads to mysql errors like:

> InnoDB: Table veno/sls37_finder_links_termsc in the InnoDB data
>   dictionary has tablespace id 1171, but tablespace with that id or name
>   does not exist. Have you deleted or moved .ibd files? This may also be
>   a table created with CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE whose .ibd and .frm files
>   MySQL automatically removed, but the table still exists in the InnoDB
>   internal data dictionary.

Answer (score 6):

To restore your database to XAMPP these are the things you need:
 -.frm , .ibd files , and ibdata1 can be found in mysql/data folder

Steps

- Install New XAMPP
- Replace ibdata1 in mysql/data
- Copy the folders of the database you want to restore [.frm and .ibd]
  and paste in mysql/data
- Run the mysql and Viola it works!

> If there is an #1932 error occur, just import the create_tables.sql
>   from xampp/phpMyAdmin/sql and this solves the problem.

Answer (score 4):

> You cannot copy a database folder that has InnoDB tables because
>   InnoDB storage engine maintains a symbiotic relationship between the
>   InnoDB tables' physical files (frm and .ibd) and the data dictionary.

Reference: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/82093/moving-binary-database-folder-is-causing-issues-with-innodb-tables

You can try (InnoDB part): https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/57120/recover-mysql-database-from-data-folder-without-ibdata1-from-ibd-files/57157#57157

**Recommendation**: It might be late in your case, however, before you move to another server, it is a good idea to export your databases to a sql file and Import it from phpmyadmin, Mysql Workbech, SQLyog or terminal

**Export:**

```
mysqldump -u user -p password database_name > database_name.sql
```

**Import**

```
mysql -u user -p password database_name < database_name.sql
```

Answer (score 2):

Continue to andread answer also copy and replace [these files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKMsf.png) to the new xampp folder.

From `\xampp\mysql\data\mysql`

Files : proc.frm, proc.MAD, proc.MAI

Answer (score 2):

I got the following logs:

```
2020-02-11 14:26:06 0 [ERROR] mysqld: Table '.\mysql\db' is marked as crashed and last (automatic?) repair failed 2020-02-11 14:26:06 0 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table '.\mysql\db' is marked as crashed and last (automatic?) repair failed 2020-02-11 14:26:06 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Well, what I did as follows:

1. Installed a new instance of XAMPP in a different directory (e.g.
   C:\xampp_new)
2. Copied back the three db files from the new installation to the old one:

> - C:\xampp_new\mysql\data\mysql\db.frm to C:\xampp\mysql\data\mysql\db.frm
> - C:\xampp_new\mysql\data\mysql\db.MAD to C:\xampp\mysql\data\mysql\db.MAD
> - C:\xampp_new\mysql\data\mysql\db.MAI to C:\xampp\mysql\data\mysql\db.MAI

3. Started MySQL service from XAMPP then it worked well.

I hope it could also be useful information for those who steps into an error like this.

> Be careful when you are trying to set privileges.