# How to restore lost databases from Uninstalled XAMPP

Tags: mysql, xampp

I Uninstalled my XAMPP without backing up the complete content and I lost all my database in the process.

I have Installed a newer version of xampp and moved my files.

Is there a way to restore the old database **please**

Comment: _I have Installed a newer version of xampp and moved my files_? Moved your file??? What does that mean? Which files?

Comment: If you still have the original folder where MySQL stores its data, then you might be able to simply copy the files - but that depends on what database engine the tables where using, for InnoDB it does not work that way. Anyway, check other questions on the topic (FYI, researching those up-front is rather what we expect from you here, and it doesn’t really look like you did that): https://stackoverflow.com/q/29258769/1427878, https://stackoverflow.com/q/42944259/1427878

Comment: This question has been flagged for moderation.  Drop the caps - we're all here to help.  Definitely more information is needed.  Be specific - what files did you delete, did you keep the MySQL .idb or .frm files etc?  Have you tried locating the MySQL data files?  Have you researched the MySQL documentation for how to recover from files on disk?

Comment: @wally just edit the title if it bothers you

Comment: The files I referred to are the files of the website i have worked on, on my local-server, I did follow on the link shared and it does not really help, sorry for my curiosity, I thought I could use more help.   the entire htdocs content is gone, but i guess I will try the MySQL documentation.   Thank you all for your help

Comment: Do you still have the old `\xampp\mysql\data` folder? Or a backup of your databases?

Comment: No.Its all gone